# tree nodeSelectListener

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

nodeSelectListener will only trigger if the node is previously not selected. If a node is already selected, and we press the same node again, the listener will not be called. how to overwrite this so that every single click even on the same node will fire  nodeSelectListener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it via that particular listener, because (by design) the select listener only fires when the node was not previously selected. See [this bug report](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-2494) for a discussion of it. You want an onclick handler instead.

Answer (score 1):

java isn't really my forte, but perhaps instead of replacing the listener altogether, you could make the onclick handler just deselect and then reselect the node?

Comment: add to ui:tree or ui:treenode ?  if i use onclick, how to get which row click by user just like when using nodeselectevent

Comment: like i say, it's really not my best subject; it was based on my experience with similar things... i was assuming it would be an onclick event on the treenode itself, and that you would get some sort of reference to the treenode that you could use to deselect and then reselect the item.  if i were set up to be able to test it out i would play around with it a little, but unfortunately i am not.  sorry not able to be more help!

Answer (score 1):

How about using `MouseListener` beside `nodeSelectListener`?

Comment: how do i add the mouselistener ?  ui:treenode ? any example?

Answer (score 0):

I really DON'T know what I'm talking about... but is this possible?

On select, collect the size and position of the node, along with the node itself.  Then on click, see if you're on the same node by seeing if the current position is within the rectangle.  Be sure to clear the saved selection info when necessary.